# Can't convert windows date format into dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, windows, date, date-conversion

I have and old custom-made program (I think it was made in Basic) that my father uses that produces some graphs and let you output a .txt file with the date you used in the graph. The output looks something like this:

```
DAXH9|0|43507.0486144213|10953|0|
DAXH9|1|43507.0486144329|10953|0|
DAXH9|1|43507.0487738889|10944|0|
DAXH9|0|43507.0487738889|10944|0|
DAXH9|0|43507.0488318519|10953|0|
DAXH9|1|43507.0488318634|10953|0|
DAXH9|0|43507.0488579398|10944|0|
DAXH9|1|43507.0488579514|10944|0|
DAXH9|0|43507.0488637153|10929|0|
DAXH9|1|43507.0488637268|10929|0|
```

And so on.

Apparently the digits in the middle are some date format (it's usually 5 digits, a dot and other 11 digits). The programmer apparently said it's a "windows date format" but I have never heard about it. I thought it was some millisecond date but converting it with JavaScript leads to poor result (date too old or too far ahead).

This is what I tried:

```
var test = new Date(STRANGE_DATE_NUMBER)
```

What date format can it be? How can I convert it?

Comment: Could be MS timestamp which is number of days since Dec 31, 1899. [Online converter](https://www.silisoftware.com/tools/date.php?inputdate=43507.0486144213&inputformat=microsoft)

Comment: Looks like an Excel serial date. See https://www.lifewire.com/serial-number-serial-date-3123991 If the original language was Visual Basic or VBA, that fits. The last one in your sample equates to 2/11/2019  1:10:22 AM.

Comment: Oh yes, that example it's from today, the program is still up and running, just I have no idea how it was made :)

Comment: The converter @JohnnyMopp linked looks accurate!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but this reminds me of certain GPS time formats, which reference a number of seconds (or milliseconds) from a specific date in the past. Here is a [GPS timer converter](https://www.andrews.edu/~tzs/timeconv/timeconvert.php?), and I put in one of your pieces of data. It gave me a date in 1995 - does that sound like the time frame you are thinking?

Comment: Nope, that should be of today! The converter in the comment look like it's working!

Comment: An answer should be an answer, not a guess. Might be suitable as a comment though. If you don't have the rep for a comment, don't post comments as answers or you'll get down voted. :-)

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the heads up!